# PHP/Session: Bring all data in table User after login

Tags: php, sql, session

currently, I create a system that requires login. I Uses the LDAP method. I have created the session for this system. When I clicked the login button, it will go to the next page and display the "User_ID". Now, How I also want to display the user's full name on the next page after clicking the login button? The full name and the "User_ID" is on the same table 'staff'

Below is my current code.

```
            <?php
        include("config/configPDO.php");
        session_start();

        $msg = ""; 
        if(isset($_POST['submitBtnLogin'])) {
        $User_ID = trim($_POST['User_ID']);
        $Pwd = trim($_POST['Pwd']);
        if($User_ID != "" && $Pwd != "") {

            $ldap_dn = "TOPNET\\".$User_ID;
            $ldap_password = $Pwd;

            $ldap_con = ldap_connect("ldap://172.xx.xx.xx:xxx");
            ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

            if(@ldap_bind($ldap_con,$ldap_dn,$ldap_password)){;
                try {

                    $records = $conn->prepare("SELECT Email, Role_ID FROM Staff WHERE User_ID = :User_ID ");
                    $records->execute(
                        array(  
                        'User_ID'     =>    $User_ID,
                        )  
                    );
                    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    $message = '';

                    if($results && count($results) > 0 ){
                        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $User_ID;
                        if($results["Role_ID"] == "2"){ 
                            header("location: pages/dashboard/dashboard_admin.php");
                        }else if ($results["Role_ID"] == "1"){ 
                            header("location: pages/dashboard/dashboard_super_admin.php");
                        }else if ($results["Role_ID"] == "3"){ 
                            header("location: pages/dashboard/dashboard_normal_user.php");
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "
                        <script>alert('You're not authorized to use this system')</script>
                        <script>window.location = 'index.php'</script>
                        ";
                    }

                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    echo "Error : ".$e->getMessage();
                }
            } else{ 
            echo "
            <script>alert('Invalid Email or Password')</script>
            <script>window.location = 'index.php'</script>
            ";
            }

        } else {
            $msg = "Both fields are required!";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the user's Full Name from Active Directory using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471771/getting-the-users-full-name-from-active-directory-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save `$results` into `$_SESSION['login_user']` and process it in the next page?